# How to run a C# script periodically?

Tags: c#, jobs, job-scheduling

Is it possible to run some C# script under Windows periodically? I mean something like a SQL job etc. I know the solution via SSIS but it's not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: A [scheduled task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)?

Comment: Why not just Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: If you are not big fan of Windows Scheduler, give a look at Topshelf. http://topshelf-project.com/

Comment: Or you could create a second project, that calls your first project periodically (using a `System.Timers.Timer`) and set up that second project to autostart with Windows, so you don't need to start it manually every time you boot your PC. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if your task is more than just periodical running of small piece of code, you are going to end up with windows service having `BackgroundWorker` thread, running some task on timer.

Here is some links to start with

[Create windows server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[How to use Background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you vittore for useful links - I will go through it.
For my small piece of c# code Win Task Schedule will be fine.
P.

Answer (score 0):

I use task scheduler for that: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows7/schedule-a-task

1. Press Windows + R, write "control schedtasks" and press enter to open the task scheduler.
2. Create a new task:
   [image: Create a task]
3. Set "Triggers" (run periodical) and "Actions" (run your script) in the menu and save.